# Python - Exit script from outside command

Tags: python, watchdog, python-watchdog

I have a proof of concept script based on the watchdog module, it registers when a new file is added to a set folder and sends off a command, this script runs constantly, but the final design is to be put on a server, meaning we will not have access to the command line to "CTRL + C" it. How do I kill it from an outside source (e.g. second script that activates a function within the primary script)?

Here is my current script, which contains a "stop_watchdog" function at the bottom.

```
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import PatternMatchingEventHandler
import os, sys, time
import sqlite3
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    patterns = ["*"]
    ignore_patterns = None
    ignore_directories = False
    case_sensitive = True
    my_event_handler = PatternMatchingEventHandler(patterns, ignore_patterns, ignore_directories, case_sensitive)

def file_detected(textInput):
    str(textInput)
    if ".txt" not in textInput:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(textInput)  # You can create a new database by changing the name within the quotes
        c = conn.cursor() # The database will be saved in the location where your 'py' file is saved
        c.execute("SELECT * FROM sqlite_master where type = 'table'")
        ##print(c.fetchall())
        textTest = "{}.txt".format(textInput)
        f = open(textTest, "w")
        f.write(str(c.fetchall()))
        f.close()

def on_created(event):
    print(f"hey, {event.src_path} has been created!")
    file_detected(event.src_path)
    ##test("{event.src_path}", shell=True)

my_event_handler.on_created = on_created

path = "./xyz"
go_recursively = True
file_observer = Observer()
file_observer.schedule(my_event_handler, path, recursive=go_recursively)

file_observer.start()
try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    file_observer.stop()
    file_observer.join()

def stop_watchdog():
    print(f"Quitting!")
    file_observer.stop()
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: Couldn't you run this in a `tmux` session? You should be able to attach to this session and kill it with keyboard interrupt...

Comment: Interesting, i have never heard of tmux before, i will look into it

Comment: *second script that activates a function within the primary script* - this looks like job for [signal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html) built-in module, though I do not know if such solution is feasbile in your environment.

Comment: A common approach would be to do this at the process level: Your script could write [its own process id](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getpid) into a designated file; your other script would read that file and issue a [kill](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.kill) with an adequate signal.

Comment: If it runs on a Linux-like os, you can use the `kill` command.